# Validar una fecha recibida desde html5 Date en java y enviarla a Mysql

Tags: java

tengo este código que funciona muy bien, recibe parámetros de unos input de un DOM y los envía por medio de ajax a un endpoint que a la vez los envía a la DB. el tema viene acá, quiero validar dos fechas, una de salida de aviones y otra de llegada, sin embargo los parámetros que están en los setString() son claramente String, con lo cual no creo poder validarlos.

Puse esos input como String ya que el input html5 me ofrece un formato tipo String "yyyy-MM-dd", el cual es el mismo formato que recibe la columna Date de Mysql. (Funciona muy bien la insercción pero ahora quiero validar)
Cómo puedo tansformar ése String que recibo de un html y poder validarlo antes a la base de datos?

Mi idea es hacer una clase estática, sin embargo estoy abrumado por la cantidad de clases relacionadas a las fechas que hay y no sé con cual hacerlo, un dato es que estoy usando java 8 y varios métodos de la clase Date no me los permite usar "deprecated".

dejo partes de código.

endpoint:

```
                        PreparedStatement ps;
                        String sql="INSERT INTO vuelos(id_avion, id_administrador, empresa, destino, escalas, pasajes, fechaSalida, horarioSalida, fechaArribo, horarioArribo, pago, precio) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        ps= con.prepareStatement(sql);

                        ps.setInt(1, id_avion);
                        ps.setInt(2, int_id_usuarioAdmin);
                        ps.setString(3, empresa);
                        ps.setString(4, destino);
                        ps.setInt(5, escalas);
                        ps.setInt(6, pasajes);
                        ps.setString(7, fechaSalida); //validar
                        ps.setString(8, horarioSalida);//validar
                        ps.setString(9, fechaArribo);
                        ps.setString(10, horarioArribo);
                        ps.setString(11, pago);
                        ps.setInt(12, precio);

                        ps.executeUpdate();
                        ps.close();

                        listado.add(new Vuelo(0,empresa,destino, escalas, pasajes, fechaSalida, horarioSalida,fechaArribo, horarioArribo, pago, precio));

                        str_toJson= gson.toJson(listado);
                        return str_toJson;

                        }
```

Parte del html:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="fechaSalida" type="date">
    </td>

    <td>
        <input id="horarioSalida" type="time" name="horarioSalida">
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <label name="fechaArribo">Fecha de arribo:</label>
    </td>

    <td>
        <label name="HorarioArribo">Horario de arribo:</label>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="fechaArribo" type="date">
    </td>

    <td>
        <input id="horarioArribo" type="time" name="horarioArribo">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ya que estas usando java 8 podrias usar DateTimeFormatter  para darle formato a la fecha. SimpleDateFormat tambien es una opcion.
Info de DateTimeFormmater aca -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Quiero comentarles a todos los que respondieron hasta el momento. Que probé todas las opciones que pasaron y funcionan excelentes,  me parecería injusto declarar una sola como correcta. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de preparar la Query sql debes realizar lo siguiente:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 

....

​SimpleDateFormat validador = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
Date fechaSalidaValida = format.parse("2017-04-12")
​​​​​​​​​​​Date fechaEntradaValida = format.parse("2017-03-01")
```

En caso, de que alguna de las dos fechas no sea válida, se lanzará una excepción la cual debes manejar en el método que llama al código que presentaste.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió, veo que a las fechas. Las convierte en String.

Comment: @berlot83 De nada, el método parse retorna un Date, el método format retorna un String según la documentación oficial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Buenas

Partiendo de que no tengas ningún control a nivel de web de lo que te pueden introducir, soluciones sencillas como el SimpleDateFormat podrían serte insuficientes.

**Solucion sencilla (pero con casos de error)**

Creo que lo que estás pidiendo es algo parecido a esto (adapta el SimpleDateFormat a tu gusto). Con lo que tengas en date, deberías poder trabajar sin problemas.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",     Locale.UK);
sdf.setLenient(false); // Importante para que valide, sino fechas como 33/01/2017 te las devolvería como su fecha correspondiente en Febrero.
Date date=null;
  try {
 date = sdf.parse("Mon Mar 14 16:02:37 GMT 2011");
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Fecha no valida o fuera de formato");
    }
```

Por temas de localización, lo ideal es que pases la fecha en sus valores numéricos, por ello, podrías llamar al SimpleDateFormat sin el locale.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

El problema reside, en que por ejemplo, incluso con setLenient(false) entradas de datos como 2017-02-3x te los daría como válidos.

**Otras soluciones**

Sugiero que eches un vistazo a las dos alternativas que proponen en este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java

La solución con JodaTime parece la forma más sencilla de lograr lo que quieres con una validación más solida.

Saludos

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir esta clase en el mismo servlet mas abajo si te complica luego importarla

```
public class parsearDate(dateInString){    
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Este metodo deberas llamarlo antes de settear.

```
ps.setString(7, fechaSalida);
```

La idea es que valides todos los campos antes de empezar a crear la instancia del objeto clase, para que una vez que todo este validado, entonces alli recien comience a settear.

Dejo ejemplo para que lo puedas ocupar para validar:

**Ej:**

```
try {
    Date date = parsearDate(fechaSalida);
    // hacer todas las validaciones

    //Comienza setteo
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    //Devolver error por que se genero un error al validar o settear
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude :D

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me sirvió

Comment: Un agrado haberte podido ayudar :D Éxito en tu proyecto :D